# How does "yield from" work in recursive functions?

Tags: python, generator

I'm writing some python code where I need to use generators inside recursive functions. Here is some code I wrote to mimic what I am trying to do. This is attempt 1.

```
def f():
    def f2(i):
        if i > 0:
            yield i
            f2(i - 1)
        
    yield f2(10)

for x in f():
    for y in x:
        print(y)
```

This only prints 10, attempt 2 using this `yield from` construct I found online.

```
def f():
    def f2(i):
        if i > 0:
            yield i
            yield from f2(i - 1)
        
    yield from f2(10)


for x in f():
    print(x)
```

This does what I want, but I don't understand what is happening, what is `yield from` doing behind the scenes and why doesn't my first attempt work?

Comment: In your first attempt, the recursive call to `f2()` is pointless - it returns a generator, but you never iterate over it, so none of the code inside it ever gets executed.  (So only one level of recursion happens, rather than the 10 levels you're requesting.)  `yield from` iterates the generator, and passes up the values it `yield`s to the next higher level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can think of `yield from` as a for loop which yields every item:

```
for i in f(10):
    yield i
```

is the same as `yield from f(10)`. In other words, it *yields* the items *from* the given iteratable which in this case is another generator.

Comment: This makes sense to me for my `f(10)` call, but i'm not sure how this generalizes to my recursive `f2(i - 1)` call.

Comment: It's the same formulation, you are saying after yielding i, for every item that f2(i-1) yields, yield it back up the chain.

Answer (score 1):

`yield from g()` will recurse inside a new generator `g` yielding from each `yield` statement at that generator

so

```
def g1():
    yield from g2()

def g2()
    for i in range(10):
        yield i * 2
```

You can think as if `yield from` in g1 was unrolling `g2` inside of it, expanding to something like this

```
def g1():
    for i in range(10):
        yield i * 2
```

This not what is happening because you have scopes and etc, but during the execution of `yield from g2()` in `g1` then interpreter recurse in `g2` yield each value that it yields, possibly recursing to another generator.

Now consider this generator

```
def flatten(maybe_it): 
    try: 
        for i0 in maybe_it: 
            for i1 in flatten(i0): 
                yield i1 
    except TypeError: 
        yield maybe_it
```

with `yield from` it can be rewrite as

```
def flatten(maybe_it): 
    try: 
        for i0 in maybe_it: 
            yield from flatten(i0): 
    except TypeError: 
        yield maybe_it
```